# How much data do we need for making a successful de-noising auto-encoder?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, keras, autoencoders, sample-complexity, denoising-autoencoder

**Is there a guide how much data do you need for making successful denoising model using autoencoders?**

Or the rule is, the more data, the better it is?

I tried with small dataset 350 samples,  to see what I will get as an output. And I failed. :D